# Fire event only on backspace: Javascript ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Javascript function, and I want to fire it only when I go back to this page using the backspace key.

I have a list of documents. When I use one of them and read the document and then press backspace, then I want to fire a function.

How can I check the event that calls the page?

Comment: You can't. The stateless nature of the web prevents you from knowing anything about happened on any other page. If you go "back", it could be returning to a cached page, so no server side code could run at all depending on the server settings. Also, don't forget that Chrome recently (made the stupid decision and) changed the key bindings so that it is now Alt + Left Arrow.

Comment: can I do it with Razor in .Net?

Comment: Razor is used to only create the HTML being sent from the server to the client, so no.

Comment: I changed the complete logic. but I think I can. there is something in HTML5 called HTML5 API. so you can control the windows history for your server using: window.history.pushState
it needs work but you can do it. thank you